# Command make:rule not defined and does not appear in the list

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am trying to create a new rule (`php artisan make:rule Captcha`) from the cmd and I get the error: `Command "make:rule" is not defined`

```
Did you mean one of these?
      make:auth
      make:command
      make:controller
      make:event
      make:job
      make:listener
      make:mail
      make:middleware
      make:migration
      make:model
      make:notification
      make:policy
      make:provider
      make:request
      make:seeder
      make:test
```

In addition, if I execute the `php artisan command`, the MAKE section only shows:

```
make:auth Scaffold basic login and registration views and routes
make:command Create a new Artisan command
make:controller Create a new controller class
make:event Create a new event class
make:job Create a new job class
make:listener Create a new event listener class
make:mail Create a new email class
make:middleware Create a new middleware class
make:migration Create a new migration file
make:model Create a new Eloquent model class
make:notification Create a new notification class
make:policy Create a new policy class
make:provider Create a new service provider class
make:request Create a new form request class
make:seeder Create a new seeder class
make:test Create a new test class
```

Any solution for the `php artisan make:rule Captcha` command to work.

I am using Laravel version 5.4.36

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Artisan make:rule command released in laravel 5.5, you have to upgrade to that version or higher, but be careful, there can be any other changes. Read laravel docs about upgrade from 5.4 to 5.5 https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade#upgrade-5.5.0

Answer (score 1):

`php artisan make:rule` was commited to the code base on 25 Jun 2017.

It seems it's available in Laravel 5.5+ as it started to be available with the L5.5 docs.